# Functional test a controller using session in symfony 6 (after the 'session' service has been deprecated)

Tags: symfony, testing, session, deprecated, functional-testing

In controllers in Symfony 5 I used to inject the `Session` and use it.

```
class MyNiceController
{
    public function __invoke( Session $session )
    {
        $this->useTheSession( $session );
    }
}
```

In the tests, I used to get it via the container and hack it like this:

```
class MyNiceControllerTest
{
    public function testWhatever()
    {
        $client = static::createClient();

        $session = $client->getContainer()->get( 'session' );
        $session->set( 'intialize-some-key', 'with-some-data' );

        $crawler = $client->request( 'GET', '/some-path' );
    }
}
```

Nevertheless, in Symfony 6 we should not use the `session` service directly as it's been deprecated:

- Deprecation note here: https://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-5-3-session-service-deprecation
- Usage of `Request` instead of `RequestStack` here: https://symfony.com/doc/current/session.html

In fact using `$client->getContainer()->get( 'session' );` fails.

Okey. The controller should be used like this:

```
class MyNiceController
{
    public function __invoke( Request $request )
    {
        $session = $request->getSession();
        $this->useTheSession( $session );
    }
}
```

## Question

I'm lost on how should I prepare the mock with the session data.

```
class MyNiceControllerTest
{
    public function testWhatever()
    {
        $client = static::createClient();

        $session = ??????????????????????????????????;
        $session->set( 'intialize-some-key', 'with-some-data' );

        $crawler = $client->request( 'GET', '/some-path' );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't exactly know what your a trying to achieve with sessions but, for user login purposes and since symfony 5.1, you can use :

```
$client->loginUser($user);
```

For other purposes something like this may work ( found when searching the updated way to login an user, not tester ) :

```
if ($container->has('session.factory')) {
    $session = $container->get('session.factory')->createSession();
} elseif ($container->has('session')) {
    $session = $container->get('session');
}
```